# How to use file Uploader in kendoui with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using kenoui uploader in angularjs,
i can able to upload files but i can't able to save that file.

my questing was how to i given saveUrl and removeUrl in option

this is my code below,

index.html

```
<input name="files"
                                       type="file"
                                       kendo-upload
                                       k-options="fileAttachmentConfig"
                                       k-select="onSelect" />
```

index-ctrl.js

```
    $scope.fileAttachmentConfig = {
        async: {
            saveUrl: 'app/images/client',
            removeUrl: 'remove',
            autoUpload: false
        }
```

}

So How to handle that saveUrl and removeUrl also how to save file to my local path?

Answer (score 0):

**saveUrl** and **removeUrl** are path to your Save/Remove method in Controller or something like that.

You must implement method in backend (server side) where you can save file on server (your local path).

Check [demos in this examples](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#server) or [C# demo server side](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/tree/master/demo).